# Way to access all mail items in an inbox using Outlook JS API?

Tags: office-js

New to the JS API for Office add-ins, trying to create an Outlook add-in with React framework. Is there a way with the Outlook API to access all mail items in an inbox or folder to perform actions? So far all I can see is the Office.context.mailbox object which only seems to return data on the currently selected email. Any thoughts?

THanks!

Answer (score 2):

Via the office.js, the Office.context.mailbox.item functions/properties only access the item that is currently selected.

It is possible to access the other items on the server via Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequest() using EWS calls.

It is also possible to use REST or EWS via getCallbackTokenAsync: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-preview#getcallbacktokenasync-options--callback-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/use-rest-api

Please note that the permissions of the token, can change depending on the permissions of the add-in.

Also those methods access/modify the Exchange server, and they may be slightly different from what you have access to in the client due to server/client syncing. (though eventually all changes will sync)